# proyecto calculo avanzado, android error: "java.lang.NullPointerException at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:285)"

Tags: android-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]estoy creando un proyecto en android studio, en primera instancia la app le pregunta al usuario que tipo de calculo desea hacer, depues de esto pide que suministre cierta cantidad de datos, debido a que eran muchos los dividi en tres activities incluyendo una para los resultados. Como los datos recogidos de cada uno deberian pasar a la ultima ventana para ser resueltos (cuarta activity si se cuenta desde el main), use intent para ello, en el primer caso no hubo problemas, pero cuando pase por la tercera activity, me dice que la aplicación tubo un error, no puedo ver donde se encuentra este alguna idea.

```
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.siguiente_electrica:


             Intent info =new Intent(SegundaActivity.this, resultados_electricos.class);
             Editable D= d.getText();
             String NCF= ncf.getText().toString();
             String A= disa.getText().toString();
             String B= disb.getText().toString();
             String C= disc.getText().toString();


            info.putExtra("fases", NCF);
            info.putExtra("diametro", D);
            info.putExtra("a",A);
            info.putExtra("b",B);
            info.putExtra("c",C);

            startActivity(info);

            Intent siguiente = new Intent(SegundaActivity.this, e_electrica2Activity.class);
            startActivity(siguiente);
            break;
```

tercera activity

```
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.siguiente2_electrica:

            Intent info2= new Intent(e_electrica2Activity.this,resultados_electricos.class);
            String RO=ro.getText().toString();
            String NHILOS= nh.getText().toString();
            String TEMP1= t1.getText().toString();
            String TEMP2= t2.getText().toString();
            String LONGLINE= longl.getText().toString();


            info2.putExtra("nhilos",NHILOS);
            info2.putExtra("temp1",TEMP1);
            info2.putExtra("temp2",TEMP2);
            info2.putExtra("LongLine",LONGLINE);
            info2.putExtra("ro",RO);

            startActivity(info2);

            Intent siguiente_2= new Intent(e_electrica2Activity.this,resultados_electricos.class);
            startActivity(siguiente_2);

            break;
```

Activity que recibe los datos:`  Button Calcular;
    int ncf;
    float d, a, b, c, ro, nhilos, temp1, temp2, LongLine;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_resultados_electricas);
    Calcular = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcular);
    Calcular.setOnClickListener(this);
    String aux_d = getIntent().getStringExtra("diametro");
    String aux_ncf = getIntent().getStringExtra("fases");
    String aux_a = getIntent().getStringExtra("a");
    String aux_b = getIntent().getStringExtra("b");
    String aux_c = getIntent().getStringExtra("c");
    String aux_ro = getIntent().getStringExtra("ro");
    String aux_nhilos = getIntent().getStringExtra("nhilos");
    String aux_temp1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("temp1");
    String aux_temp2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("temp2");
    String aux_LongLine = getIntent().getStringExtra("Longline");
```

//para convertir variables a numeros//
        d = Float.parseFloat(aux_d);
        ncf = Integer.parseInt(aux_ncf);
        a = Float.parseFloat(aux_a);
        b = Float.parseFloat(aux_b);
        c = Float.parseFloat(aux_c);
        ro = Float.parseFloat(aux_ro);
        nhilos = Float.parseFloat(aux_nhilos);
        temp1 = Float.parseFloat(aux_temp1);
        temp2 = Float.parseFloat(aux_temp2);
        LongLine = Float.parseFloat(aux_LongLine);

```
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.calcular:
            if (ncf == 1) {
                double rmg = (d / 2.0);
                double dmg = Math.pow(a * b * c, 1.0 / 3.0);
                double area = (Math.PI) * (Math.pow(rmg, 2.0));
                double resist = (ro * 1000) / area;
                double resisttemp = ((228 + temp2) / (228 + temp1)) * resist;
                double resisline = resisttemp * LongLine;
                double inductancia = ((1 / 2 * ncf) + (4.6 * (dmg / rmg))) * 0.0001;
                double reacinduc = inductancia * (Math.PI) * 120;
                double reacinducline = reacinduc * LongLine;
                double capac = (24.2 * 1E-9) / (Math.log(dmg / rmg));
                double reaccap = capac * 120 * (Math.PI);
                double reaccapline = reaccap * LongLine;
            }

            break;[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]`
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

El error que da en logcat `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.abraham.myapplication/com.example.abraham.myapplication.resultados_electricasActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                     at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:285)
                                                                                     at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:300)
                                                                                     at com.example.abraham.myapplication.resultados_electricasActivity.onCreate(resultados_electricasActivity.java:31)
                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
                                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Comment: " me dice que la aplicación tubo un error" y cual es el mensaje de error en el LogCat? si no usas el LogCat estarás buscando horas determinando un problema en lugar de segundos. Agrega el mensaje que se muestra

Comment: Can't bind to local 8700 for debugger. Este es el ultimo mensaje que da, pero solo lo hace cuando se instala la app en el emulador

Comment: Gracias por agregar el LogCat, es muy importante en desarrollo android, agregué una respuesta, simplemente asegura enviar los datos en el Intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al utilizar los putExtra, estas enviando uno o varios atributos entre actividades, al recibir el atributo en la actividad de destino asegurate que los estas obteniendo con la el id que le asignaste en la actividad anterior.

Ejemplos:

Actividad 1:

`i.putExtra("miID", strName);` <--- envias el atributo con el id asignado en este caso se llama `miID`.

Actividad 2:

`newString= extras.getString("miID");` <--- obtienes el atributo con el id que le asignaste

Comment: Gracias, revise y si tienen los id's correctos. Pero aun asi no funciona. Alguna otra idea?

Comment: He notado que estas llamando dos veces la actividad, en la primera le envias los atributos y el segunda no le envias nada.           
      `startActivity(info2);`<--- Esta es la primera ves que los llama la actividad 
            `Intent siguiente_2= new Intent(e_electrica2Activity.this,resultados_electricos.class);
            startActivity(siguiente_2);`  <----- y esta es la segunda ves .               **Elimina la segunda segunda  actividad e intentalo nuevamente.**

Comment: Elimina Intent siguiente_2 y compila

Comment: 'Intent info2=newIntent(e_electrica2Activity.this,resultados_electricos.class);
            String RO=ro.getText().toString();
            String NHILOS= nh.getText().toString();
            String TEMP1= t1.getText().toString();
            String TEMP2= t2.getText().toString();
            String LONGLINE= longl.getText().toString();
            info2.putExtra("nhilos",NHILOS);
            info2.putExtra("temp1",TEMP1);
            info2.putExtra("temp2",TEMP2);
            info2.putExtra("LongLine",LONGLINE);
            info2.putExtra("ro",RO);
            startActivity(info2);'

Comment: También verifica que estas recibiendo todos los atributos de la actividad anterior, recuerda que solo puedes recibir atributos de una sola actividad y no de varias al mismo tiempo, al menos que guardes cada atributo en la actividad que lo  recibe y vuelves enviar esos atributo a la siguiente actividad y repites la misma secuencia hasta donde quieras, lo cual seria algo tedioso y te recomendaría mejor usar la sql lite para guardar.

Comment: Ante todo gracias por la ayuda. En este punto debo preguntar, ¿sera buena idea rehacer la activity para que todos los datos que deben ser introducidos, queden en una sola y de hay se hagan los cálculos?

Comment: Me alegra haberte ayudado :), respecto a tu pregunta, si estos formularios tienen mucha complejidad lo mejor seria hacerlo separados, para evitar mucho lineas de código que complicarían el mantemiento, en este caso usa la base de datos de android, mira este  tutorial veras que es facil:
 http://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/javaya/androidya/androidstudioya/detalleconcepto.php?codigo=16&inicio=0

Comment: Por ultimo si vas hacer todo en una sola actividad, usa POO para separar la parte lógica del programa del control de la interfaz, así te resultara mas facil programar y al mismo tiempo vas a tener tu código limpio.

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta especificado :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException                                                                                 at java.lang.StringToReal.parseFloat(StringToReal.java:285)
at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:300)
at com.example.abraham.myapplication.resultados_electricasActivity.onCreate(resultados_electricasActivity.java:31)
```

Este problema se genera cuando tratas de convertir a Float un valor null:

```
Float.parseFloat(null)
```

Debes asegurar enviar los datos en el Intent, en este bloque de código puedes ver el problema:

```
  switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.siguiente2_electrica:

            Intent info2= new Intent(e_electrica2Activity.this,resultados_electricos.class);
            String RO=ro.getText().toString();
            String NHILOS= nh.getText().toString();
            String TEMP1= t1.getText().toString();
            String TEMP2= t2.getText().toString();
            String LONGLINE= longl.getText().toString();


            info2.putExtra("nhilos",NHILOS);
            info2.putExtra("temp1",TEMP1);
            info2.putExtra("temp2",TEMP2);
            info2.putExtra("LongLine",LONGLINE);
            info2.putExtra("ro",RO);

            startActivity(info2);

            Intent siguiente_2= new Intent(e_electrica2Activity.this,resultados_electricos.class);
            startActivity(siguiente_2); //* No se estan enviando valores en este Intent.

            break;
```

Al realizar el intent para abrir resultados_electricos, no estas agregando los valores:

```
       Intent siguiente_2= new Intent(e_electrica2Activity.this,resultados_electricos.class);
        startActivity(siguiente_2);
```

por esa razón cuando tratas de obtenerlos tienen valor null.

Comment: disculpa la ignorancia pero ¿que debo hacer para que no fuese nula?. en la seundaActivity lo declare de la misma manera y pudo hacer el paso de esa a la siguiente activity.

Comment: Si revisas el código estas agregando valores al Intent "info2" en cambio a el intent "siguiente_2" (que abre resultados_electricos) no agregas ninguno, agreaga a el intent "siguiente_2" valores.

Comment: bien elimine el intent info2, y deje todo los elementos asociados al intentent siguiente_2 y asigne todos los valores que este tenia (info2) a siguiente_2. pero el problema persiste.

Comment: Tienes que asegurar que los valores que envias son los valores que recibes mediante su llave,  getIntent().getStringExtra("<llave>"); si no son los mismos el problema persistira

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda hasta ahora. Revise, las key son las correctas. incluso elimine la clase y volví a crearla, ya que creía que tal vez el manifest  tenia un error. Ya que leí que este error aveces se relaciona con un error ahí.

Comment: Estas realizando 2 intent , solo revisa que lo que envias a una Activity es lo que intentas leer.

Comment: elimine el intent info2, para luego cambiar todos los info2.putExtras todo a siguiente_2.putExtras("llave", String)